# Setear varios componentes a la vez

Tags: java

Estaba buscando si existe alguna funcion para setear varios componentes al terminar un formulario jinternalframe y no tener que setear uno por uno en "", se me ocurria un arreglo de componentes, pero no me parecio la mejor idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal para estos casos es crear un método que setee los componentes que quieras a "" como dices y llamarlo cada vez que necesites realizar esta acción.

```
public void limpiar(){
    componente1 = "";
    ...
}
```